# Twisting Words!

Tags: code-golf, string

## Twisting Words!

Given a string and a positive integer. You must twist the string, back and forth.

#### Example Input / Output

Input

```
Programming Puzzles & Code Golf
4
```

Output

```
Prog
mmar
ing 
zzuP
les 
oC &
de G
 flo
```

### Input

The input can be taken in through STDIN, or function argument. The input will consist of a string and a positive integer, *n*. The integer will determine the length of each twisted line.

The string is twisted back-and-forth. An input of `HELLO, WORLD!` and 5 would look like:

[image: HELLO, WORLD!]

### Output

The output will be the twisted text. It may not any trailing whitespace. If the input string length is not divisible be the line length, add a space until the line is filled:

An example of this:

Input

```
Hello, World!
5
```

Output (Note the whitespace at the very end)

```
Hello
roW ,
ld!
```

Comment: Related: [a readable implementation at CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/101738/twisting-words-ruby)

Comment: *It may not any trailing whitespace.* Golfed away a verb?

Comment: May we return a list of lines?

Comment: While working on this, I was wondering if this was made a bit more challenging. In addition to twisting the words, we should also find patterns that match between two lines. For example, if the word was `This pearl was made from the peas` and we broke it by 4 chars, then `aep ` will appear on line 2 and line 8. We need to identify the matches. If there are more than one match, then we need to print all the matches including line number that matched :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>19</s> 15

```
VPc+z*dQQ_W~!ZN
```

Pre-pads the string, then reverses each other line as it prints it. The padding is equal to the size of the box, but the last line after chopping up the input is discarded.

[Try it here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VPc%2Bz*dQQ_W%7E!ZN&input=Programming+Puzzles+%26+Code+Gol%0A4&debug=0)

Answer (score 7):

## CJam, 19 bytes

```
q~1$S*+/W<{(N@Wf%}h
```

Input example:

```
5 "Hello, World!"
```

#### Explanations

```
q~         e# Input n and the string.
1$S*+      e# Append n spaces to the string.
/W<        e# Split by each n characters, and remove the last chunk.
{          e# While the array of chunks isn't empty:
    (N     e# Extract the first chunk and push a newline.
    @Wf%   e# Reverse every chunk left in the array.
}h
```

Answer (score 7):

### Python 2, 60

```python
s,n=input()
d=1
while s:print(s+n*' ')[:n][::d];s=s[n:];d=-d
```

Takes `n` characters at a time from the from of `s`, printing them with a direction `d` that alternates between `1` and `-1`. For spacing on the last line, `s` is padded with `n` spaces at the end before it is chopped, which only affects it when it has fewer than `n` characters remaining.

A recursive solution would save a char (59) except that it leaves a trailing newline, which is not allowed.

```python
f=lambda s,n,d=1:s and(s+n*' ')[:n][::d]+"\n"+f(s[n:],n,-d)
```

Answer (score 5):

### [Snowman 1.0.1](https://github.com/KeyboardFire/snowman-lang/releases/tag/v1.0.1-beta), 91 bytes

```
{vg10vg|sB*#.'aGal'NdE'aaAaL|al!*+#5nS" "'aR'!#aCwR|.aC2aG:0aa|sP"
"sP'NdE|1aA.aNsP"
"sP;aE
```

Or all on one line (for aesthetics, or more specifically, anti-aesthetics), at the cost of 2 bytes:

```
{vg10vg|sB*#.'aGal'NdE'aaAaL|al!*+#5nS" "'aR'!#aCwR|.aC2aG:0aa|sP10wRsP'NdE|1aA.aNsP10wRsP;aE
```

This is way too short, for Snowman. (It's probably the shortest it can get, though; I worked on golfing this for a pretty long time.)

This has one caveat: it will exit with an error (but still produce the correct output) 50% of the time, when the last line is *not* reversed. (This is because I use `ag` to group the array elements in groups of two so that I can reverse every other one, but I don't check whether the last element has both expected elements, so it'll try to access a nonexistent element if there are an odd number of lines.)

Ungolfed / explanation:

```
{vg10vg|sB*#      // get input, convert second string to number and store
.'aG              // split string into groups of n chars
al'NdE'aaAaL      // take out the last element of the array
|al!*+#5nS" "'aR  // subtract its length from 5, repeat that many spaces
'!#aCwR|.aC       // concat spaces to last el. and that back to the array
2aG               // split in groups of 2, so we can reverse every other string
// for each sub-group in the array of groups...
:
    0aa|sP10wRsP         // print the first element as is
    'NdE|1aA.aNsP10wRsP  // print the second element, reversed
;aE
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>83</s> 75 bytes

```hs
(id!)
(f![])_=[]
(f!l)n=f(take n$l++cycle" ")++'\n':((f.reverse)!drop n l)n
```

Simple `chunksOf` implementation with take and drop, applying an even or odd number of reverses to the output as we go.

Thanks to @BMO for five bytes and @ØrjanJohansen for three bytes!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcuxCsIwEADQ3a@4hmITgk5OQiYH14JjWySkl1p6TUISBfvxRt3e8h46LUhUsuoLn8dK7LitukHcVTf8ScIpy7NeEFxNUpq3IWTAhJRN75oz5/YY8YUxoajG6AM4@J2y6tmBgvDMtxyhhgysjX6Kel1nN0H73DbCBHu4@BHh6skyOJWPsaSnVA4mhC8)

Comment: Using `cycle` saves 5 bytes, [try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcoxCsMgFADQvaf4SmgU6dap4NSha6BjEoIYtSE/KmoKzeFr@@b3Unk1iLXIobJlJsm8TcqGn9hEJj71o@zHE7PEcQ8oLStqNeAbFEJ/NBoKlAvRDr69MUcs92xOIcL/8rqpxYOEuJdnSdBAgSvQLgWX1LYt3kG3HweaDGe4h9nAI6Cl9astKpfrRcf4Aw "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: Save three more bytes by removing `g` and swapping `n` and `l`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcuxCsIwEADQ3a@4hmITgk5OQiYH14JjWySkl1p6TUISBfvxRt3e8h46LUhUsuoLn8dK7LitukHcVTf8ScIpy7NeEFxNUpq3IWTAhJRN75oz5/YY8YUxoajG6AM4@J2y6tmBgvDMtxyhhgysjX6Kel1nN0H73DbCBHu4@BHh6skyOJWPsaSnVA4mhC8 "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>22</sup> <sup>15</sup> 13 bytes

```
]`|."1@(]\)~-
```

*-2 bytes thanks to xash*

Note the above solution requires J901, which allows you to apply cyclic gerunds using the rank `"` conjuntion.  TIO uses an older version, so to run this one you have to download J.

However, my previous solution of 15 bytes will work on TIO:

### 15 bytes

```
([]`|.\[:,]\)~-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcxBC4IwGIDhu7/iQ8lt4b4SOo2SkVCXCOk6F0apGdrA6GKyv76CunR4Tw@8N@cjqWAlgEAEcxCfOEJ62G0cVboYMVci0jmz3DFvv0agSugwKeiIYcJmuPRjJqnOLf9xgzIYUeqjUP4cYv2nXH6f@oVWTWmCcmID5nnl@WqAZL2p@1PXNfcasucwtOUDQkjNpYStaSsCFSzcGw)

Finally, another 15 byte alternative, thanks to @Marshall and based on a trick from @ngn, is:

```
([:|.@]/\]\)~-
```

Comment: Your output seems to be incorrect for the final line of the test case you've used (trailing space instead of leading).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Sadly fixing that one small thing ruined the elegance of the solution (╥﹏╥)

Comment: :( You did fix it though, so +1 from me. :)

Answer (score 4):

## [Stuck](http://kade-robertson.github.io/stuck/), <s>42</s> <s>41</s> <s>40</s> 38 Bytes

This is a wee bit too long, probably will try to golf more!

```
tg;_lu_@%u;-_0G<*' *+0GKE"];2%;Y_Y?p":
```

Input should be like `"string"|n`.

Explanation:

```
tg                 # Take input, place each item on stack, save the int to variable stack                                        
;_l                # Swap the top two items, duplicate the string and obtain length
u_@%               # Rotate to the left, duplicate, rotate right and take mod
u;-                # Rotate left, swap the top two and subtract from each other
_0G<*              # duplicate this value, check if less than stored int and multiply
' *+               # Push space onto stack n times, append to starting string
0GKE               # Split this string into segments, and enumerate
"];2%;Y_Y?p":      # For each segment, determine if should be reversed, and print
```

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 19 bytes

```apl
{↑⊢∘⌽\↓↑⍵⊆⍨⌈⍺÷⍨⍳≢⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P/FR24TqR20TH3UtetQx41HP3phHbZNB/N6tj7raHvWueNTT8ah31@HtIGbv5kedi4Aytf//mygkKqgHFOWnFyXm5mbmpSsElFZV5aQWK6gpOOenpCq45@ekqXOZglR5pObk5OsohOcX5aQoqgMA)

Took the `⊢∘⌽\` trick from [ngn's brilliant answer to the boustrophedonise challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/150153/41805).

After realising that my submission breaks for lines with leading newlines, I have added two more bytes. Below is the older submission.

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 17 bytes

```apl
{↑⊢∘⌽\⍵⊆⍨⌈⍺÷⍨⍳≢⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P/FR24TqR20TH3UtetQx41HP3phHvVsfdbU96l3xqKfjUe@uw9tBzN7NjzoXAWVq//83VUhUUPdIzcnJ11EIzy/KSVFUBwA)

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, 87 bytes

```
sub f{$_=@_[0].$"x(@_[1]-1);$a.=(($i++&1?reverse$1:$1).$/)while/(.{@_[1]})/g;chop$a;$a}
```

Old version (prints a trailing newline):

```
sub f{$_=@_[0].$"x(@_[1]-1);print(($i++&1?reverse$1:$1).$/)while/(.{@_[1]})/g}
```

String is passed as a function argument with no trailing newline. Call like this:

```
$_=<>;chomp;print f($_,5);
```

Answer (score 3):

### PowerShell, 102 Bytes

```
param($s,$i)$l=$s.Length;$s+' '*($i%$l)-split"(.{$i})"|?{$_}|%{$r=-not$r;@($_,($_[$l..0]-join''))[$r]}
```

Invoked as follows (if saved to file `CodeGolf55051.ps1`)

```
.\CodeGolf55051.ps1 -s '1234567890' -i 4
```

---

### Previous Attempts

(longer or invalid)

**PowerShell, 110 Bytes**

```
param($s,$i)$l=$s.Length;$s+' '*(($i-$l%$i)%$i)-split"(.{$i})"|?{$_}|%{$r=-not$r;@($_,($_[$l..0]-join''))[$r]}
```

**PowerShell, 111 Bytes**

```
param($s,$i)$s+' '*(($i-$s.Length%$i)%$i)-split"(.{$i})"|?{$_}|%{$r=-not$r;@($_,($_[$_.length..0]-join''))[$r]}
```

**Explanation**

```
param($s,$i)                         #Take input text (s) and column width (i)
$s                                   #take the user entered string
+ ' ' * (($i - $s.Length % $i) % $i) #add the least number of spaces required to make its length divisible by i
-split"(.{$i})"                      #break it into chunks of i characters in length
| ?{$_}                              #skip any blank lines created in the process
| %{                                 #for each line
    $r = -not $r;                    #    toggle a boolean value
    @(                               #    define an array
        $_                           #    index 0 = the string going forwards
        ,($_[$_.length..0] -join '') #    index 1 = the string reversed (by taking each character from the last to the first, then joining them)
    )[$r]                            #    if our boolean value is false take the forward string (index 0), if true take the backwards one (index 1)
}                                    #next
```

**PowerShell, 180 Bytes**

```
param($s,$i)$x="`${0}|{1}|`${2}";$w=$x;1..$i|%{$w=$w-f$_,$x,($i+$_)};$w=$w-replace'\||\${.*}';$r=$w-replace'\$\d+','(.)?';$s+' '*($i-$s.Length%$i)-replace$r,$w-split"(.{$i})"|?{$_}
```

**PowerShell, 196 Bytes**

```
param($s,$i)$x="{0}|{1}|{2}";$w=$x;1..$i|%{$w=$w-f$_,$x,($i+$_)};$w=$w-replace'(\d+)','$$$1'-replace'\||{.*}';$r=$w-replace'\$\d+','(.)?';$s+' '*($i-$s.Length%$i)-replace$r,$w-split"(.{$i})"|?{$_}
```

**Explanation**

```
param ($s, $i)                      #Take input text (s) and column width (i)

$x = "{0}|{1}|{2}"                  #Define string format which takes 3 entries and pipe delimits them

$w = $x                             #initialise our replacement regex with this format
1..$i | %{                          #for 1 to the specified column width
    $w = $w -f $_, $x, ($i + $_)    #update the regex 1|{...}|5, 1|2|{...}|6|5, etc
}                                   #resulting in w = 1|2|3|4|{...}|8|7|6|5
$w = $w -replace '(\d+)', '$$$1'    #now prefix the numbers with a dollar (so they're regex replacement variables)
        -replace '\||{.*}'          #and remove the delimiters and superfluous `{...}` left from our middle insertion routine

$r = $w -replace '\$\d+', '(.)?'    #then create the match pattern by replacing the variables with optional single character captures

$s                                  #now take the user entered string
    + ' ' * ($i - $s.Length % $i)   #add the least number of spaces required to make its length divisible by i
    -replace $r, $w                 #perform a replacement using the regex match and replace patterns created above
    -split "(.{$i})"                #then split the string into blocks of length i
    | ?{$_}                         #removing any blank lines created in the process
```

(`{...}` in the above comments is actually `{0}|{1}|{2}`; I put `{...}` for improved readability.

**Powershell, 120 Bytes**
(invalid)

```
param($s,$i)$s + ' ' * ($i-$s.Length%$i) -replace '(.{4})?(.)(.)(.)(.)',"`$1`n`$5`$4`$3`$2`n" -split "`n" | ?{$_ -ne ""}
```

Comment: Awesome to see another PowerShell slinger! An easy start is to get rid of dang near every space ``param($s,$i)$s+' '*($i-$s.Length%$i)-replace'(.{4})?(.)(.)(.)(.)',"`$1`n`$5`$4`$3`$2`n"-split"`n"|?{$_-ne""}``
which will get you down to 108.

Comment: Thanks @TimmyD; just spotted a couple of fundamental errors with my script though (it doesn't meet the requirements / is hardcoded to only work for 4... fixing now)

Comment: While testing, to get the flow back and forth to start in the correct direction, I needed to swap the final `[$r]` index with `[-not$r]` ... else the first line reads the opposite (i.e., right-to-left) than in the examples provided. Otherwise, really slick execution!

Comment: Also, since we're given that the input number `n` is positive, and we're guaranteed that the length of the string is non-negative (by definition), that means that `(($i-$l%$i)%i)` is equivalent to `($i-$l%$i)`, saving four characters.

Comment: Thanks @TimmyD; though is that true (i.e. I=3;L=6 gives 0 with the original and 3 with the shortened version).

Comment: Whoops, I somehow typo'd that, I originally meant `(-$l)%$i`. Don't know where that came from. Interesting, however, that it's not equivalent, though it should be. It's apparently a quirk of how PowerShell (among other languages) implements the modulo function, which is different than either I (being a math major) or Wolfram-Alpha expected. Apparently, you'll need to stick with the longer version. [Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)

Proof --> `((y-x%y)%y) ==> ((y%y)-(x%y%y))%y ==> ((0)-(x%y))%y ==> (-x%y)%y ==> (-x)%y`

Answer (score 3):

### Mumps, 86 bytes

```
R I,S,! S P=$L(I),$P(I," ",P)=P F Q=1:S:P S F=$E(I,Q,Q+S-1),P='P W $S('P:F,1:$RE(F)),!
```

Although it could be 2 bytes shorter if you remove the first ',!' characters in the R statement (read from STDIN); that adds a carriage return between the input and output. If that wasn't there, the output is technically correct, but the first line would appear appended to the input string. *[[ The standard Mumps terminal that I use has no local echo. ]]*   As it sits, here's the test:

```
R I,S,! S P=$L(I),$P(I," ",P)=P F Q=1:S:P S F=$E(I,Q,Q+S-1),P='P W $S('P:F,1:$RE(F)),!
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1236
ABCDEF
LKJIHG
MNOPQR
XWVUTS
YZ123
```

Also note, there's actually a carriage return / Enter keypress between the '123' and the '6' at the end of the input. *[[ The local echo thing again. ]]*

If anyone's interested I can describe what's going on with the code; but I do realize there's not a ton of Mumps enthusiasts out there... :-)

Answer (score 3):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 51 bytes

```perl
$_.=$"x(($-=<>)-1);say--$|?$_:~~reverse for/.{$-}/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHBCoJAEADQu1@xxRIKzaqQF8s6dKhL4K2jCI4ijDsyW1FWfnrbeyMKZd7ryhR6@QxDDcVuH0EabV39AtCfg67yeRZ8oDhULUts3hq@ced9KdxJPQy97VR5nyZCp1bqyA2qE1MbbIIzEvFaXVmoWQTZj8dbz9Z5sOThkpkkTf4)

Answer (score 3):

### Clojure, 83 bytes, <strike>87 bytes</strike>, <strike>79 bytes</strike>

```
(fn[n s](map #(apply str(% %2))(cycle[#(or %)reverse])(partition n n(repeat\ )s))))
```

several corrections after comments below, thank you [Ørjan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66041/%C3%98rjan-johansen).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3LTsMwEEX3@YpLqiBbgg2CL2ABy@5YpF1YzqSYjh@MnUrtzwe7YWZ3z9wzluPPIrSuaqIZvgPUHMaAfFTeJOyUSYmvyEXUgOFFa2WvlmncqSgYtNCFJNNRq2SkuOJiQF0llMiUA3TWdbqu2QPsN9kz7vb2iKlgFMoLFyhfe1m3vJIpZvrFyC4QtoMNVJQkoOX/3k35in4v8STGexdO2C@3G1PGI97jRPiIPPe6q1UXCgf0z/dp0VZ/Q/9JzPEJX1F4eqhkXf8A)

Clojure seems often sadly absent from code golfing answers. It certainly can not compete in byte length with golfing languages, but I think the total absence is somewhat unwarranted.

Explanation:

- in-data, two arguments a number and a string
- start by running clojure built-in function [partition](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/partition) on string `s` chunking it into a sequence of lists of characters where the lists have length `n`. The last chunk will be padded with spaces to length `n` using the "pad collection" returned from `(repeat " ")` which returns an infinite lazy sequence of spaces
- we then call [map](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map) with three arguments:

  - an anonymous function (the `#(..)`)
  - an infinite alternating lazy sequence of functions `#(or %)` which functions like the [identity](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/identity) function and [reverse](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reverse) (i.e. `[#(or %) reverse #(or %) reverse ...]`) as returned by [cycle](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/cycle).
  - the chunked up lazy sequence of lists returned by partition.
- finally the [anonymous function](https://clojure.org/guides/learn/functions#_anonymous_function_syntax) `#(apply ...)`:

  - calls either `identity` or `reverse` alternatingly on a chunk. This is done via the `(% %2)` expression which calls the function sent in as the first argument to the anonymous function [i.e. `identity` or `reverse`] using the second argument [i.e. the chunk] to the anonymous function as the argument to the call.
  - calls `(apply str ...)` to convert the list of characters into a string
- the outer function returns a lazy sequence of strings

one trick we use here is that a lot of clojure functions like `map` take an arbitrary number of collections as args, i.e. `(map f coll1 coll2 coll3 ...)` where the function f just needs to accept as many arguments as there are collections. In this case we send in two collections, a collection of alternating function references and the chunked up string.

Comment: This is nice but it doesn't seem to have the required whitespace at the end of `ld!  `.

Comment: You are most correct. Added a pad collection which should fix the issue...and cost me 8 bytes...

Comment: I have a question on golfing rules: if you are using a built-in function which would require an import or similar statement (require in clojure, import in java, etc), does the importing of that built-in need to be part of the golfing solution byte count? I assume yes, but it feels a tad like a gray area.

Comment: Yes, the import is counted.

Comment: Oh but there's another rule you're breaking: You cannot take input in predefined variables, you need to make the solution either a whole program or a function. (Using either `fn` or `defn` is fine.) On the flip side your function is allowed to just return the result rather than print it.

Comment: I suppose `#()` is also fine, I don't really know Clojure.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers and apologies for noobness with golfing rules. Added function and now return a sequence of strings instead of printing them.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, <del>110</del> <del>108</del> <del>107</del> 103 bytes

```python
def a(s,n):l=len(s)//n+1;s+=' '*(len(s)-l);print('\n'.join([s[x*n:n*x+n][::(-1)**x]for x in range(l)]))
```

(looking at other answers), with `rjust`: <del>95</del> <del>93</del> <del>92</del> 90 bytes

```python
def a(s,n):print('\n'.join([s[x*n:n*x+n][::(-1)**x].rjust(n)for x in range(len(s)//n+1)]))
```

Comment: The last line of your output is wrong. [Run it here.](https://tio.run/##FcqxDsIgEADQ3a@4Se6w2jQ6sTq4dscOJAXE0KOBmmB/HuOb3/rdXomvrc3WgcHSMakDrDnwhuLJ4vJOgVEXXSUrllhPA01aKTwPJGWdwKUMFQJDNuwtRstYqO/5/4iaQTHm5LNZlsAexs@@R1vgCPc0W3ik6EQHN2o/) It's a great first post, and once you fix that I will suggest some ways to golf some bytes off, the first being that you can remove all the spaces/tabs from your answer.

Comment: haha, you're so right. fixing this is gonna cost a lot but i'm on it. thanks

Comment: [Tips for golfing in Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/54/34718)

Comment: Also, you beat my answer from quite a while ago: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55082/34718

Comment: reading the tips. thanks again

Comment: [Make sure you count your bytes correctly.](https://tio.run/##JcixDoMgEADQ3a@4qdyh1ph2InFy6OpuHUhES4OHAZtQf54OfePbv8fL8y3n2SygMVZMqgDXOcMYqWm4bAuIZSdASPxn7aiAPVg@UDxZXN/eMo5xTJIVS0xlS9OoFNYtSZkmWHyABJYhaF4NOpqIskYxBL8GvW2WVxg@5@lMhAv0fjbw8G4RFdwp/wA)

Comment: i forgot the newline. sorry and thanks for editing

Answer (score 2):

## Lua, <s>91</s> <s>88</s> <s>88</s> <s>84</s> <s>83</s> 82 bytes

Old version:

```lua
a=arg for i=1,#a[1],a[2]do s=a[1]:sub(i,i+a[2]-1)print(d and s:reverse()or s)d=not d end
```

New version:

```lua
arg[1]:gsub((".?"):rep(arg[2]),function(s)print(d and s:reverse()or s)d=not d end)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 108 bytes

```
(#)=splitAt
s!n=let(a,t)=n#s;(b,u)=n#t in a:reverse b:(u!n)
s%n=unlines$takeWhile(any(>' '))$(s++cycle" ")!n
```

That's sort of long, jeez. Here it is in action:

```
*Main> putStrLn $ "Programming Puzzles & Code Golf" % 4
Prog
mmar
ing
zzuP
les
oC &
de G
 flo
```

Comment: How does binding the `let` expression work?

Comment: It's a two-in-one `let` statement separated by a semicolon -- normally you'd use newlines and indentation, but Haskell also allows you to write `let a=b; c=d in expr`.

Comment: I didn't know this was allowed, taking putStrLn out of the program!

Comment: @LeifWillerts, recently, challenges on here tend to allow you to either perform I/O via function arguments/results or stdin/stdout -- here, my solution is a function `(%) :: String -> String -> String` instead of `IO ()`.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 109 bytes

Had to add padding with spaces for the last line to be correct.

[**Try it here**](http://ideone.com/54nKxW)

```python
I,c=input()
I+=(c-len(I)%c)*" "
L=[]
i=0
while I:s=I[:c];L+=[[s,s[::-1]][i%2]];i+=1;I=I[c:]
print"\n".join(L)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Q, <s>64</s> 56 bytes

```
{c::neg y;-1(til(#)l){$[x mod 2;c$(|:)y;y]}'l:y cut x;}
```

- `{}` is a function that should be called as `{}[x;y]`.

  - `x` will be the string.
  - `y` will be the length of the resulting lines.

Test:

```
{c::neg y;-1(til(#)l){$[x mod 2;c$(|:)y;y]}'l:y cut x;}["Programming Puzzles & Code Golf";4]
Prog
mmar
ing
zzuP
les
oC &
de G
 flo
```

**edit**: Used shorter functions as inspired by the other [q answer by @tmartin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55119/21697)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <strike>82</strike> 75 bytes

```
s,n=input()
k=0
while k<=len(s):print s[k:k+n].ljust(n)[::1-2*(k/n%2)];k+=n
```

I couldn't comment on @willem but I made his code smaller.

<strike>[Try here](http://ideone.com/jpDwEF)</strike>
[Try here](http://ideone.com/Qu5l6r)

Comment: Hi AlexN, nice one. I think that your last line in the 'Try here' example is not correct. It should be justified right. Also I count 86 chars? See [my entry](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55051/twisting-words/55085#55085) for the update.

Comment: Hi willem, you are right, I corrected the code and found that you have an error in yours:
http://ideone.com/GOmMrE

There should be a t on the right side.

Answer (score 2):

## O, 60 bytes

```
z""/rlJ(Q/{n:x;Q({+}dxe{`}{}?p}drQJQ%-{' }dJQ/e{r}{}?Q({o}dp
```

My very first O program, and a long one at that!

[Live demo.](http://o-lang.herokuapp.com/link/code=z%22%22%2FrlJ(Q%2F%7Bn%3Ax%3BQ(%7B%2B%7Ddxe%7B%60%7D%7B%7D%3Fp%7DdrQJQ%25-%7B%27+%7DdJQ%2Fe%7Br%7D%7B%7D%3FQ(%7Bo%7Ddp&input=Programming+Puzzles+%26+Code+Golf%0A4)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript ES6, 123 bytes

```
var t=(s,n)=>{for(var d=1,i=0,o='',l=s.length;i<l;i++){o+=d?s[i]:s[i-i%n+n-1-i%n]||' ';if(i%n==n-1){d=!d;o+='\n'}}return o}
```

Call with `t(input_string, twist_length)`, which returns the output string.

Comment: Sorry, posted a bit too fast. It's fixed.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 72 bytes

```
perl -p0e's/\n(.*)/$"x($1-$-[0]%$1)/e;s/.{$1}/($i++%2?reverse$&:$&)."\n"/ge;chop'
```

70 bytes, plus 2 bytes for `-p0`.

Demo:

```
$ echo -en 'Hello, World!\n5' | perl -p0e's/\n(.*)/$"x($1-$-[0]%$1)/e;s/.{$1}/($i++%2?reverse$&:$&)."\n"/ge;chop'
Hello
roW ,
ld!  $
```

Note that the input read from STDIN cannot end with a newline (that would cost 2 extra bytes).

Explanation:

```
perl -p0e'  # Read from STDIN, splitting on null bytes,
            # and print $_ automatically at the end

    s/
        \n(.*)  # Replace everything after first newline,
                # capturing wrap length in $1...
     /
        $"x($1-$-[0]%$1)  # ...with spaces until the total length of $_ is
                          # a multiple of $1 (i.e. right-pad with spaces)
     /e;

    s/
        .{$1}  # Replace series of $1 contiguous chars...
     /
        ($i++%2?reverse$&:$&)."\n"  # ...alternately with themselves or in
                                    # reverse, with a trailing newline
     /ge;

    chop'  # Remove final newline
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
òV ËzEÑÃù
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=8lYgy3pF0cP5&input=IlByb2dyYW1taW5nIFB1enpsZXMgJiBDb2RlIEdvbGYiCjQ)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 64 bytes

[Try Online](https://tio.run/##BcGxCsMgEADQvV9xZCgKtlCyXXDqkDW7OAgxicWcwTPU5ufte8evbIn61ma/gBOsSFX9kniD7xaiB8YjByqCDZJ95s/JRZA0iNXKgTUbQjtU/ajNiW7Kac1u3wOtMJ3XFT3DHd5p9jCmuHQKetnaHw)

```
def a(s,n,x=1):
 while s:print(s[:n].rjust(n)[::x]);s=s[n:];x=-x

a('Programming Puzzles & Code Golf',4)
```

Step 1: Print the first n bytes of the string (flag = 1 so normal order)
Step 2: Trim the string by n bytes
Step 3: Flip the flag to -1
Repeat the process until string is empty

Note that flag flips to +1 and -1. When it goes to -1, it prints in reverse order

Comment: The question doesn't specify a third parameter. The function header should be `a(s,n,x=1)`

Comment: @JoKing, agreed. Fixed. Also fixed the rjust() problem.

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, 135 bytes

Takes two command-line arguments as shown with `$argv`.

```php
<? foreach($a=str_split($s=$argv[1],$n=$argv[2])as$k=>&$v)$v=$k%2?$v:strrev($v);echo implode("\n",$a).str_repeat(' ',$n-strlen($s)%$n);
```

Answer (score 1):

### CoffeeScript, 131 bytes

This seems too long.

```coffee
f=(s,n,r=l=s.length,i=0,z='')->(t=s[i...i+=n].split '';t=t.reverse()if r=!r;z+=t.join('')+(i<l&&'\n'||' '.repeat n-l%n))while i<l;z
```

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 104 bytes

```julia
f(s,n)=(L=length(s);L+=L÷n;j=0;for i=1:n:L-n+1 x=rpad(s,L)[i:i+n-1];println(j%2<1?x:reverse(x));j+=1end)
```

Ungolfed:

```julia
function f(s::String, n::Int)
    L = length(s) + length(s) ÷ n
    j = 0
    for i = 1:n:L-n+1
        x = rpad(s, L)[i:i+n-1]
        println(j % 2 == 0 ? x : reverse(x))
        j += 1
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 86 bytes

Here's my answer (borrowing some input processing from [@mbomb007](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55051/twisting-words/55082#55082)). Unfortunately can't define the len(s) as a variable as the length of the string changes after padding with spaces. Now also using rjust() instead of ljust() as [@AlexN](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55051/twisting-words/55110#55110) suggested.

```
s,n=input()
k=n
while k<=len(s):print s[k-n:k]+'\n'+s[k+n-1:k-1:-1].rjust(n);k+=2*n
```

Answer (score 1):

### Shell/Bash, 135 bytes

```shell
s=0;while true;do ((s%($2*2)))&&{ echo "${1:s:$2}"|rev;s=$((s+$2)); }||{ echo "${1:s:$2}";s=$((s+$2)); };((s>=${#1}))&&{ exit 1; };done
```

Comment: Would it be possible to replace the `true` with either `1` or `1=1`?

Comment: Yes, you can do `while :`. I didn't see this answer when I composed [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55174/43035), but it has very similar logic, and I borrowed the more concise arithmetic evaluation to [reduce](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/55174/revisions) my version from 83 bytes to 74.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 101 bytes

```
t,x=eval(input())
print("\n".join([t[c:c+x].ljust(x)[::1-2*(int(c/x)%2)] for c in range(0,len(t),x)]))
```

[Try it here](http://ideone.com/6Oxrqj)

Answer (score 1):

## q, 46

```
{-1@neg[y]$@[a;(&)(til(#)a:y cut x)mod 2;|:];}
```

.

```
q){-1@neg[y]$@[a;(&)(til(#)a:y cut x)mod 2;|:];}["Programming Puzzles & Code Golf";4]
Prog
mmar
ing
zzuP
les
oC &
de G
 flo
```

Comment: This is incorrect when the last line is shorter and not twisted, I wanted to post the bug fix in my answer but I think it'll be better if you can update yours instead: `{-1@[l;(&)(til(#)l:y cut x)mod 2;'[neg[y]$;|:]];}` (49 bytes). Thanks for the inspiration! :)

Answer (score 1):

## Coffeescript, 151 bytes

```
f=(s,n)->r="";d=n;i=0;_="\n";u=" ";l=s.length;(d--and(r+=s[i]or u;++i)or(r+=_;r+=s[c]or u for c in[i+n-1..i];i+=d=n;r+=_ if i<l))while i<(l/n+1>>0)*n;r
```

Too much =(

Answer (score 1):

## Bash, <s>83</s> 74

```
for((i=0;i<${#1};i+=$2));do b=cat;((i/$2%2))&&b=rev;echo ${1:i:$2}|$b;done
```

This alternates between `cat` and `rev` for substrings of the first argument with a length of the second argument.

Special variables used include

- `${#1}` (the length of the string `$1`)
- `((i/$2%2))` (an arithmetic expression dividing incrementor `$i` by `$2` and then taking its modulo to determine odd vs even, which dictated whether or not to use `rev`)
- `${1:i:$2}` (substring of `$1` starting at position `$i` with a length of `$2`).

Comment: Hm, I did this independent of the other `bash` answer, which I only just saw now.  We have effectively the same logic. ... actually, [viktorahlström's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55086/43035) just let me shave off another 9 characters.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript ES6, 113 bytes

Just my own crack at my own question. It will add spaces so it is divisible by `n`, that way it's simply splitting and reversing.

```
(s,n)=>(s+' '.repeat(n-s.length%n)).match(eval(`/.{1,${n}}/g`)).map((l,i)=>i%2?[...l].reverse().join``:l).join`
`
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>145</s> 141 bytes

Not allowing trailing whitespace made it clunkier than otherwise.

Thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat) for the tip that led me on the track to save 4 bytes.

```c
f(s,n,l,i,j)char*s;{for(l=strlen(s),i=0;i<l;i+=2*n)if(printf("%-*.*s\n",n,n,s+i),i+n<l){for(j=i+2*n;j>i+n;)putchar(l/j--?s[j]:32);puts("");}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY2xTsMwFEXn5iuMJZCd2IBaWHADgkLbsRtDYYjSODzrxa7sdGmVbw@vwMh4r849t9ZtXY@jFUl5hQqUk/VXFfNkTjZEgWXqIzZeJKmgvDUwRwNFOc29BCv2EXxvBb/U@XWePjwnh1epAIILP0f543AlFDQw7pFKI/eH/vwg8MZp/ZS27vNhNpWG6iQ4l2YYRrKyrgIvZHbKJnSwiaGNVdeBb9nmcDxik9gVW4Rdw1YBLVfsTpps8uvQWvNzot26QQyKvYeIuwui7v@lnl8Wr2/L1fpPM4zf)

Answer (score 1):

### Groovy, 68 bytes

```
f=-n;s.eachMatch(/.{1,$n}/){printf "%${f}s%n",f>0?it[-1..0]:it;f=-f}
```

revised after I realized the initial version didn't handle padding correctly.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYy9CsIwGAD3PMVnaKWF9EfQxaIODroI3RzEobRJW8iPJFGwIc8ea2@@u14r9fmG0FEGIjEEZAoOAbBDJiuT06Ydbo1th6TI3YZE0hepe@lRWgY4jhzzJpaYsGN5Gu0j2@R5@dyPtppz5pFHSACutep1I8Qoe6jf08SpgTWcVUfhojjDBLZoWXIJOFvA/@5KOVcE7krzbjVbuxB@)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>197</s> <s>146</s> 136 bytes

```java
s->n->{String r="",t,u;for(int l=s.length,i=0,j;i<l/n*n+n;r+=t+"\n",i=j)for(t="",j=i;j<i+n;t=j++/n%2<1?t+u:u+t)u=j<l?s[j]:" ";return r;}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hZA9T8MwEIZ3fsVhCZSQ1AUESx2nAxIfA1KlDgylg0nSYOPakX2u1Fb97cFRy4ZAuuF074f0nBIbMVL1V19p4T28Cmn2ZwAeBcoKVFRpQKnpKpgKpTX08bQUc3TStItl/qfrxWDTNi6Ho70soQLe@1FpRuX@eAPHCckxD2xlXSINguae6sa0@JlLfp0rJgs9NlcmM8xlHDPybkhUVDoEcEgrLpkqZDQgV1k2Nhe3xc0UszAJGaaBq0JP/UItJwQIcw0GZ8CxQ88ia5wufOiIe6LeWFnDOn4i@WEEkQ5fAZhvPTZragPSLkqoTVJR0XV6m5CZs60T6/WANAu7nW48XMKDrRt4snpFqO@0xISQND1F7tKU/Vv73Ghtc3izTtfnv5TcH0sOZ4f@Gw)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->n->{                 // Method with String and integer parameters and String return-type
  String r="",          //  Result-String, starting empty
         t,u;           //  Temp-Strings
  for(int l=s.length,   //  Length of the input-String
      i=0,j;i<l/n*n+n   //  Loop `i` in the range [0, `l` + whatever to make blocks of `n`)
      ;                 //    After every iteration:
       r+=t+"\n",       //     Append the result-String with `t` and a new-line
       i=j)             //     And set `i` to `j`
    for(t="",           //   Reset `t`
        j=i;j<i+n;      //   Inner loop `j` in the range [i, i+n)
        ;t=j++/n%2<1?   //     After every iteration: If the k'th block of `n` is even:  
            t+u         //      Append `u` to `t`
           :            //     Else (it's odd):
            u+t)        //      Prepend `u` to `t`
      u=j<l?            //    If `j` is still within bounds:
         s[j]           //     Set `u` to the current character
        :               //    Else:
         " ";           //     Set `u` to a space
  return r;}            //  Return the result-String
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 14 bytes

```
óV y £Yv ?X:Xw
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///DmMIVKhUOLI8sU7COsIsr//1cKKMpPL0rMzc3MS1cIKK2qykktVlBTcM5PSVVwz89JU@Iy4eLSDQIA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 34 bytes

```
Fla.sXb-#(@RVa<>b)<>b{Po?lRVlo!:o}
```

Similar approach as to my [Boustrophedonise answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/150117/boustrophedonise/210418#210418), but with padding and splitting the string.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P/fLSdRrzgiSVdZwyEoLNHGLkkTiKsD8u1zgsJy8hWt8mv////vkZqTk6@jEJ5flJOi@N8UAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 22 bytes

```
ô0UεRDg²s-úXÈiR}X>U}}»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUcAuP9vc2FiaWX//8O0MFXOtVJEZ8Kycy3DuljDiGlSfVg@VX19wrv//1Byb2dyYW1taW5nIFB1enpsZXMgJiBDb2RlIEdvbGYKNA)

Bring on the golfing suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
sz⁶ZUÐeY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7@46lHjtqjQwxNSI////68UUJSfXpSYm5uZl64QUFpVlZNarKCm4Jyfkqrgnp@TpvTfBAA)

```
s           Slice the left argument into pieces (right argument) long.
 z          Zip it with filler
  ⁶         " ",
   Z        zip it back,
    U       reverse the slices
     Ðe     at even 1-indices,
       Y    and join on newlines.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 20 bytes

```
⟨{ġ|,Ṣ↰}lᵛ⟩{i↔ⁱ⁾}ᶠ~ṇ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6kUFCUn1KanFpsxaX0cFen/aO2DY@amoCshzu2Acnah1snPOpYrqSnVP7/0fwV1UcW1ug83LkIqKo25@HW2Y/mr6zOfNQ25VHjxkeN@2ofbltQ93Bn@///0dFKAUX56UWJubmZeekKAaVVVTmpxQpqCs75KakK7vk5aUo6JrE60UoeqTk5@ToK4flFOSmKSjqmIDG4Goh6kAHOGYk5Oal56anFSjrmRKgxBqkpSC1KS00uScssARkcCwA)

Takes input as a list `[string, slice length]`.

```
⟨{     }                To the string, apply the following predicate:
  ġ                     split it into slices of roughly equal length,
   |                    or
    ,Ṣ                  append a space
      ↰                 and recur.
        lᵛ⟩             ...such that each slice has the prescribed length.
                  ~ṇ    The output, split on newlines, is
           {    }ᶠ      every possible result from
            i           taking a slice with its 0-index
             ↔          and reversing
               ⁾        the slice
              ⁱ⁾        a number of times equal to the index.
```

I'm a bit ashamed to have only come up with this the moment I had finished explaining my previous solution:

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 22 bytes

```
{|,Ṣ↰}ʰġ₎z₂z{i↔ⁱ⁾c}ᶠ~ṇ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6kUFCUn1KanFpsxaX0cFen/aO2DY@amoCshzu2Acnah1snPOpYrqSnVP6/ukbn4c5FQAW1pzYcWfioqa8KqLKqOvNR25RHjRsfNe5Lrn24bUHdw53t//9HRysFFOWnFyXm5mbmpSsElFZV5aQWK6gpOOenpCq45@ekKemYxOpEK3mk5uTk6yiE5xflpCgq6ZiCxOBqIOpBBjhnJObkpOalpxYr6ZgTocYYpKYgtSgtNbkkLbMEZHAsAA)

```
      ʰ                   Apply the following predicate to the input string:
{|                        leave it unchanged, or
  ,Ṣ                      append a space
    ↰}                    and recur.
       ġ                  Split the string into slices
        ₎                 of the given length (except maybe the last one).
         z₂z              Each slice has the same length.
                    ~ṇ    The output, split on newlines, is
            {     }ᶠ      every possible result from
             i            taking a slice with its 0-index
              ↔           and reversing
                ⁾         the slice
               ⁱ⁾         a number of times equal to the index
                 c        (then concatenating it, as the zipping exploded it).
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3, 95 bytes

```
s,z=eval(input());p=0
while p<len(s):a=s[p:p+z].ljust(z);print(a[::-1] if p%(2*z) else a);p+=z
```

Try it here online:
https://ideone.com/F4aY4d

Comment: [TIO seems to only count 94 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcqxDoIwEADQ3a@4kGhaQaPiVO3k4MpOGJp4QM3RNrRovJ@vvPmFXxq9q3OOFWv8GBLWhSUJKW9Bnzbf0RJCuBM6EaUyOrZBhZK7I72XmASvbbYuCdMqdTh3YHsIW3HZswSkiGDWUGrOuWhmP8xmmqwboFmYCSPs4OFfCE9PfVHB9Q8). ...also note that "it may not any trailing whitespace".

Comment: @UnrelatedString: what does it mean by "it may not any trailing whitespace"?

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `jr`, 5 bytes

```
ẇ↲⁽Ṙẇ
```

[Try it online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJqciIsIiIsIuG6h+KGsuKBveG5mOG6hyIsIiIsIjVcbkhlbGxvLCBXb3JsZCEiXQ==)

Explanation:

```
ẇ      # Get chunks of length n.
 ↲     # Pad each one with spaces to make it n chars long.
    ẇ  # On every second item, call:
  ⁽    # a one element lambda that
   Ṙ   # reverses it's input.
       # Join on newlines with j flag.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 80

```rb
->s,l{s+=' '*(l-s.size%l)
(s.size/l).times{|i|puts [x=s[i*l,l],x.reverse][i%2]}}
```

Online demo: http://ideone.com/w6o8PI